# What is a suitable state feedback adaptive law in discrete time?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, stability

I am trying to find a discrete adaptive law and prove stability in an analogous way to a well-known case in continuous time. Let me give a rough explanation of the background.

In **continuous time**, let us consider a LTI system:
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = Ax + Bu(t)\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector; $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix, whose elements are unknown; $B$ is a known $n \times m$ matrix; $u$ (control input) is a $m \times 1$ vector. If all states are accessible, and if a so-called **matching condition** exists, 
it is possible to design the control input $u$ such as to force system \eqref{1} to behave like a desired reference model. Let this reference model be written as :
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_m}{\mathrm{d}t} = A_mx_m + Br(t)\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where dimensions of $x_m, A_m, r$ are similarly defined.
To force system \eqref{1} to behave like system \eqref{2}, we select $u$ as follows:
$$ 
u(t) = \Theta^*x(t) + r(t)\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
where $\Theta^*$ is m x n matrix. It is easy to check that substituting \eqref{3} into \eqref{1} gives exactly \eqref{2} if $A_m = A + B\Theta^*$ (this is the so-called **matching condition**).
Since we don't know the entries of $A$ (that is the whole point of adaptive control), we do not know $\Theta^*$ exactly a priori. We only know it exists. It will be the job of the adaptive controller to compute this using an adaptive law. So it is more appropriate to re-write \eqref{3} as:
$$
u(t) = \big(\Theta^* + \Theta(t)\big)x(t) + r(t)\label{4}\tag{4}
$$
Where $\Theta$ is $m \times n$ matrix representing the error in estimating $\Theta^*$, which adaptive controller should eventually force to 0.
A suitable  adaptive law is:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\Theta(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = -B^T\!Pe(t)x(t)^T \label{5}\tag{5}
$$
Where $e(t) = x(t) - x_m(t) $ is $n \times 1$ error vector; $P$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix (sometimes also called Lyapunov matrix).
The adaptive law \eqref{5} can be shown to be valid by checking the stability of the whole system. A lyapunov candidate is selected:
$$
V = e^T\!Pe + \mathrm{Trace}(\Theta^T\Theta)\label{6}\tag{6}
$$
It can be shown (I will not write the proof here for the sake of brevity) that $\mathrm{d}V/\mathrm{d}t < 0$ and with Barbalat's lemma, conclude that the system consisting of \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, \eqref{5}, and $e$ is asymptotically stable.

I am attempting a similar derivation in **discrete time**. Re-write the LTI system \eqref{1} as:
$$ 
x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)\label{7}\tag{7}
$$
Let the reference model be:
$$
x_m(k+1) = A_mx_m(k) + B_mr(k)\label{8}\tag{8}
$$
Where $A, B, A_m, B_m$ are discretized matrices with same dimensions as before.
Let the input be chosen as:
$$
u(k) = (\Theta^* + \Theta(k))x(k) + r(k)\label{9}\tag{9}
$$
The error vector is:
$$
e(k) = x(k) - x_m(k)\label{10}\tag{10}
$$
$$
\implies e(k+1) = x(k+1) - x_m(k+1) = A_me(k) + B\Theta(k)x(k)\label{11}\tag{11}
$$
Before I pick the adaptive law, I want to point out something on the Lyapunov candidate function. I picked a function:
$$ 
V(k) = e^T(k)Pe(k) + \mathrm{Trace}\big(\Theta(k)^T\Theta(k)\big)\label{12}\tag{12}
$$
$$
\implies V(k+1) = e^T(k+1)Pe(k+1) + \mathrm{Trace}\big(\Theta(k+1)^T\Theta(k+1)\big)\label{13}\tag{13}
$$
The discrete 'derivative' of $V$ is:
$$
\begin{split}
\Delta V &= V(k+1)-V(k) \\
& = e^T(k+1)Pe(k+1) + \mathrm{Trace}\big(\Theta(k+1)^T\Theta(k+1)\big) \\
&\qquad - e^T(k)Pe(k)  - \mathrm{Trace}\big(\Theta(k)^T\Theta(k)\big)
\end{split}\label{14}\tag{14}
$$
A few manipulations will lead to:
$$
\begin{split}
\Delta V  & = e^T(k)(A_m^TPA_m - P)e(k) + 2e^T(k)A_m^TPB\Theta(k)x(k) \\
& \;\;+ x(k)^T\Theta^T(k)B^TPB\Theta(k)x(k) + \mathrm{Trace}(\Theta(k+1)^T\Theta(k+1) - \Theta(k)^T\Theta(k))
\end{split}\label{15}\tag{15}
$$
The goal is to show that $\Delta V < 0$. The first term in \eqref{15} is equivalent to $-e^T(k)Qe(k) < 0$ where $Q$ is Positive Definite. So the 1st term is good. So I must pick an adaptive law such that the rest of the terms also add up to $< 0$. Several tries later, the closest I was able to get to cancel those terms is with the adaptive law:
$$
\Theta(k+1) = \Theta(k) - B^TPA_me(k)x(k)^T\label{16}\tag{16}
$$
Substituting into \eqref{15}, and after a few manipulations, we get (I'll drop the $k$ since it adds no new information):
$$
\Delta V = -e^TQe + x^T\Theta^TB^TPB\Theta x + x^Txe^TA_m^TPBB^TPA_me\label{17}\tag{17}
$$
Alas, the gods of Lyapunov functions have not been kind to me because I am unable to eliminate the 2nd and 3rd terms in \eqref{17} above. For now I have run out of adaptive law candidates. Or maybe I picked a bad Lyapunov function?
Does anyone have experience with discrete time state feedback adaptive control? Any pointers to picking the adaptive law and/or Lyapunov function?
I've looked at Gang Tao's *Adaptive Control Design and Analysis* book. Chapter 4 deals with continuous time adaptive state feedback, but it falls short of the discrete analysis, instead going for discrete output feedback.

Thanks,
Ed.